# SQL 2019 -Group by Id and Date field

Tags: sql, group-by, date-range, gaps-and-islands

SQL 2019 I'm having difficulty to generate similar groups by date.

This is the source table and image what is expected

```
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmpType')) IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE  #EmpType


CREATE TABLE #EmpType
(
    EMPID INT,
    EmpType VARCHAR(10), 
    PayPeriod DATETIME
)


INSERT INTO #EmpType (EMPID, EmpType, PayPeriod)
SELECT 1, 'Contractor', '2019-12-20'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Contractor', '2020-01-08'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Contractor', '2020-01-22'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Perm', '2020-05-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Perm', '2020-05-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Contractor', '2020-06-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Contractor', '2020-06-20'

INSERT INTO #EmpType (EMPID, EmpType, PayPeriod)
SELECT 55, 'Temp', '2019-12-20'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'Temp', '2020-01-08'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'Temp', '2020-01-22'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'Perm', '2020-02-05'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'Perm', '2020-05-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'Perm', '2020-05-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'Temp', '2020-06-10'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'Temp', '2020-06-20'
UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'Temp', '2020-06-29'

SELECT * FROM #EmpType
```

I need to get a result that has 4 columns: EmpID, EmpType, StartDate, EndDate

| EmpID | EmpType | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Contractor | 12/20/2019 | 1/22/2020 |
| 1 | Perm | 5/1/2020 | 5/10/2020 |
| 1 | Contractor | 6/20/2020 | 6/20/2020 |
| 55 | Temp | 12/20/2019 | 12/20/2019 |
| 55 | Perm | 2/5/2020 | 5/10/2020 |
| 55 | Temp | 6/10/2020 | 6/29/2020 |

[Expected result formated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbmfL.png)

I was using `MIN` and `MAX` date and `ROW_NUMBER (PARTITION BY )`, but it combines `EmpType` into same group even there's other `EmpType` entry in between

Thank you

Comment: what database system are you usung and please show us your treys  and explain what is wrong with them

Comment: Please don’t link to images, show all information as editable text